# Is there a FilterEvent in the yadcf

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Is there a way to capture the filter query? I need to send the filter query to the server, so that when the user exports the data, it is honored there as well and the user sees the same file as the report on the web.

Comment: [exGetColumnFilterVal?](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)

Comment: Do you have more information than a link to the home page of the project?

Comment: yadcf does not broadcast any events, but it listening to events that are being broadcast by datatables, if you will explain your flow and provide your datatable init code I migth help you more